# BigQuery Python library loading datetime inconsistently

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, google-bigquery

I am using the Python BigQuery library (`google-cloud-bigquery==3.3.0`) to write data into BigQuery from a Pandas dataframe.

This library is inconsistently creating BigQuery columns of type `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`. I can't figure out what is determining the type a given column is written as.

I have written a class which sets an attribute value (`processed_datetime`) to the current time (`datetime.now()`) in the class constructor.

The class also has a method which creates and returns a dataframe. That method sets the value of the `processed_datetime` column in the returned dataframe to that of the `processed_datetime` object attribute.

I can therefore be sure that the `processed_datetime` column values for each dataframe created by the instance:

1. Have the same datetime value;
2. Are of the same datetime type (`datetime[64ns]`).

The following isn't a real implementation but gives an example of the set-up:

```
class ExampleClass: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.processed_datetime = datetime.now()
    def new_df(self): 
        data = {'a':'Some value', 'b':'Some other value'}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.processed_datetime = self.processed_datetime
        return df

example_class = ExampleClass()
df1 = example_class.new_df()
df2 = example_class.new_df()

bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df1, [...])
bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df2, [...])
```

In this example, I can be sure that df1.processed_datetime and df2.processed_datetime have the same values / type, but in one instance may be written to BigQuery as a `DATETIME` type, and in another are being written as a `TIMESTAMP`.

What can be causing this? What can I do to mitigate?

Comment: Hello j_marvin! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. A secondary action would be to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you think it's useful. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can assist by specifying the schema in the `job_config`. Note: Specify a (partial) schema. All columns are always written to the table. The schema is used to assist in data type definitions. Specify the type of columns whose type cannot be auto-detected.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("processed_datetime", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.DATETIME),
        bigquery.SchemaField("a", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df1, table_id, job_config=job_config
) 
job.result()
```

You can see the full code sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe#code-sample).